# javascript const keyword is not working

Tags: javascript, html

**my.js**

```
function deductions(){
    parseFloat($('#TaxDeduction').val());        // value 5
}

function earning() {
    const itdeduction = deductions();
    var basicsalary = parseFloat($('#BasicSalary').val());  //value 10000
    var da = parseFloat($('#DA').val());       // value 1000
    var totalearning = Math.round((basicsalary+da));   // value 11000
    var it_deduction = Math.round(((totalearning * itdeduction) / 100)); //value 550
    $('#TaxDeduction').html(it_deduction.toFixed(2));
    $('#TaxDeduction').val(it_deduction.toFixed(2)); //value 550 on first mouse over //value 60500 on second mouseover. but  i Need value 550 for n number of mouseover
}
```

**my.html**

```
onmouseover="earning()"
```

In this the onmouseover event my const keyword in javascript is not working. or else the on each time onmouseover TaxDeduction value gets increased.

Comment: can you please describe your problem more accurately

Comment: Can you explain *not working*? Also when you say `HTML`, please provide entire markup of element and not just how you are assigning event listener

Comment: Im taking some value like eg 5 in onchange event for Taxdeduction field, then Im calculating that with totalearning inorder to achieve in amount. Each time in mouseover it takes the value of calculated amount. but I need only 5 in that for TaxDeduction field

Comment: @Rajesh once itdeduction was assigned it never changed. I need same value for each calculation.i.e. 5

Comment: If missing `return` is not the problem, it should work fine. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brqyt0kd/)

Comment: @TomažBratanič I need itdeduction value never changed, once assigned

Comment: @Rajesh on each time mouseover the value is changing for deductions(). I need same value for each mouseover. In javascript I am reassigning that to calculated value. the again mouseover it takes the last calculated value and the value is increasing

Comment: You are misunderstanding the purpose and function of the const keyword. Your script is doing exactly what you're telling it. You're modifying the input with each call so naturally it changes. You would have to save the desired value in another field or different scope so it can persist outside of the function call and then be sure not to override it.

Comment: @Christopher can we use static / final keyword in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `return`:

```
 return parseFloat($('#TaxDeduction').val());
```

Comment: sorry after adding return. Each time in mouseover it takes the value of calculated amount. but I need only 5 in that for TaxDeduction field. 5 in the sense only use that for each onmouseover

Comment: how to load once the value static const final value in javascript